# Communicate with NewPOS terminal via HCE (NFC)

Tags: android, terminal, nfc, hce

i have question about compatibility of **HCE** technology (Host Card Emulation NFC) and NewPos (POS technology) terminals.

> According to Google HCE documentation - it supports only ISO/IEC 7816-4 specification.

<sup>Source: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html)</sup>

NewPos terminals (we got NewPos 8110 series) supports this:

> Mifire classic, Mifire Ultralight, Mifire DESFire, ISO 14443 A & B, SONY FeliCa.

<sup>Source: [www.newpostech.com](http://www.newpostech.com/en/product/productdetail.aspx?id=100000012791437&proTypeId=100000003641532)</sup>

Does that mean there is no way to use Android-phone (v4.4 with HCE support) to communicate with NewPos 8110 terminal through NFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this situation by myself (with Sony Xperia Z3 Compact, Android 4.4 with HCE). 
Results are:

1. NewPos 8110 terminal detects phone as a smart card;
2. Contacless card readers (like OMNI, ACR etc.) detect phone as a card, but card type is unknown and UID is not generated (it is how HCE work).